# How can I read Xml then write a Xml in different format in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I would need to get the value of the attributes of each elements even if they are inconsistent. Like my example One person can have multiple birth date and i need to present the output with the same number of birthdate. You can see the raw data and sample output.

I already tried using xmlnodelists with foreach but what it does is that it includes all birthday in one person even if it doesnt belong to that person.

Here is the sample of the raw data xml

```
<element>
<details firstName="testfirst" middleName="testmiddle" lastName="testlast" wholeName="testwholename" function="testjob">
</details>
<bdate bdate="1900-02-01" place="testplace" country="testcountry">
</bdate>
</element>
<element>
<details firstName="testfirst1" middleName="testmiddle1" lastName="testlast1" wholeName="testwholename1" function="testjob1">
</details>
<bdate bdate="1900-01-01" place="testplace1" country="testcountry1">
</bdate>
<bdate bdate="1900-01-02" place="testplace2" country="testcountry2">
</bdate>
<bdate bdate="1900-01-03" place="testplace2" country="testcountry2">
</bdate>
</element>
<element>
<details firstName="testfirst2" middleName="testmiddle2" lastName="testlast2" wholeName="testwholename2" function="testjob2">
</details>
<details firstName="testfirst3" middleName="testmiddle3" lastName="testlast3" wholeName="testwholename3" function="testjob3">
</details>
<details firstName="testfirst4" middleName="testmiddle4" lastName="testlast4" wholeName="testwholename4" function="testjob4">
</details>
<bdate bdate="1900-01-04" place="testplace3" country="testcountry3">
</bdate>
<bdate bdate="1900-01-05" place="testplace4" country="testcountry4">
</bdate>
</element>
```

This should be the output

```
<ELEMENT>
<FULLNAME>testwholename</FULLNAME>
<FIRSTNAME>testfirst</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>testmiddle</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>testlast</LASTNAME>
<POSITION>testjob</POSITION>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-02-01</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
</ELEMENT>
<ELEMENT>
<FULLNAME>testwholename1</FULLNAME>
<FIRSTNAME>testfirst1</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>testmiddle1</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>testlast1</LASTNAME>
<POSITION>testjob1</POSITION>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-01</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace1</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry1</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-02</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace2</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry2</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-03</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace3</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry3</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
</ELEMENT>
<ELEMENT>
<FULLNAME>testwholename2</FULLNAME>
<FIRSTNAME>testfirst2</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>testmiddle2</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>testlast2</LASTNAME>
<POSITION>testjob2</POSITION>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-04</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace3</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry3</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-05</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace4</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry4</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
</ELEMENT>
<ELEMENT>
<FULLNAME>testwholename3</FULLNAME>
<FIRSTNAME>testfirst3</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>testmiddle3</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>testlast3</LASTNAME>
<POSITION>testjob3</POSITION>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-04</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace3</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry3</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-05</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace4</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry4</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
</ELEMENT>
<ELEMENT>
<FULLNAME>testwholename4</FULLNAME>
<FIRSTNAME>testfirst4</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>testmiddle4</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>testlast4</LASTNAME>
<POSITION>testjob4</POSITION>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-04</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace3</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry3</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
<BIRTH>
<DATE>1900-01-05</DATE>
<PLACE>testplace4</PLACE>
<COUNTRY>testcountry4</COUNTRY>
</BIRTH>
</ELEMENT>
```

Comment: You should post the code you have already.

Comment: Why you don't use 'Serialize' and 'Deserialize'?

Comment: This is a completely trivial transformation in XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a little XPath to help with this.

```
// Select all <details> that exist under a <element>
var inputPeople = document.SelectNodes("//element/details");
foreach (XmlElement inputPerson in inputPeople)
{
    ...

    // Select all <bdate> that exist in the same <element> as the <details>
    var inputBirthdates = inputPerson.SelectNodes("../bdate");
    foreach (XmlElement inputBirthdate in inputBirthdates)
    {
    }

    ...
}
```